# Azure DevOps - organizing projects and repositories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc, azure-repos, azure-boards

---

(Posting the question here as this is the 'community' that Microsoft redirects to with a *'Need advice? Ask community'* button. Hope it won't get closed as *'primarily opinion based'* or *'too broad'*)

---

Hello,

I want to start using AzureDevops in my department for organizing code & work. We're a **small team** who creates a **large number of applications** & plugins.

Some of these applications have a **very short lifecycle**, i.e. we deliver them, and they work for years without changes. Other apps are larger and are **updated/fixed across several months or years**.
These applications are **completely separate from each other in all aspects**.

As far as I understand Azure DevOps structure, my department should become an 'Organization' (we can/need to be separate from the rest of the corporation).

I am a bit puzzled about the 'Project' part. Documentation says

> In general, we recommend that you use a single project to support your organization or enterprise.

So, let's say we do have one project called `Our Apps` - where do we then put all the individual application-projects?

As far as I understand, each **product** (application) that we deliver should have it's own repository (or a set of applications, if they are logically connected).

This is in order to allow a developer to simply clone the repo on their machine and contribute to that **product** only - without downloading other projects etc.

I need to be able to:

- **easily navigate/see** all the tens/(hundreds?) of applications that we create,
- view their **separate kanban** boards (for those project that do have it, not all of them will)
- to see their repositories (Git or TFS), commits etc
- see & manage their pipelines

At the moment it seems to me that the only place where I can see a 'list' of *what **products** do we have* is the drop down below:

[image]

And the only way to see *what is going on in the big-enough-to-get-own-board products* is by **creating a new separate 'SomeApp Team'** in the Project (even though same people are in it), so that I can have a board for the SomeApp - and view the boards from here:

[image]

1. Is that the intended way to organize the structure?
2. Any alternative approaches?
3. Is there any way to have a 'cross-reposistory' or 'cross-team' overview?
4. What about creating documentation for each 'product'?

Comment: See also: https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/

Comment: Cross team views: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "[one project to rule them all](https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/)" was coined by Martin Hinshelwood and his blog post from way-back-when explains the reasons and limitations.

With the introduction of Tagging and filtering on the backlog there is an alternative approach within the one-project setup.

- Create team for the real teams you have in your organisation.
- Create an area path for each major project/product in the org.
- Assign the area paths of the projects to the teams who are working on them. This can change over time.
- Optionally tag work items with the major project/product for additional filtering.

This way each team sees a complete view of *all the work* they can pull from. And they can quickly filter the work by tags to remove items from view when discussing specific projects/products.

Also, when teams change their focus from one product/project to another, you can simply change the assigned areas for that team to update their view.

The [Plan View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans) extension provides an additional cross-team view across over all the work. And the [Dependency Tracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-eswm.dependencytracker) extension can visualize dependencies over time.

You can also use the Epic/Feature/PBI|UserStory tree structure to create additional grouping in your work items. You can customize the process template to introduce a Product level, though for the planning features to work, that would also mean that you'd also have to create full traceability from Product down to PBI|UserStory.

The main recommendation is to try a few of these approaches in a light-weight manner to see how they work and find your own ideal setup.

Another option for cross project visualization is to enable the [Analytics Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics) and [connect it to PowerBI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops).

As you'll soon figure out, naming guidelines for your Tags, Repositories, Pipelines is going to be very important. Being able to quickly filter to the right level requires this.

Comment: Images on Martins blog are broken at the moment, looks like right-click, open in new  window shows them.